# How to use pagination to display one item per page

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

I want to display one fact per page using pagination but it displays all facts in one page.

Here is the controller am using

```
$config = array();
    $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "Admin/news/index";
    $config["total_rows"] = $this->news_model->record_count();
    $config["per_page"] = 2;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 1;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $data["results"] = $this->news_model->fetch_countries($config["per_page"], $page);
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

And this is model

```
public function record_count() {
    return $this->db->count_all("knowbank");
}

public function fetch_countries($limit, $start) {
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $query = $this->db->get("knowbank");

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
    return false;
```

}

Finally my view

```
              <?php foreach ($news as $news_item): ?>
      <div class="col1"><?php echo $news_item['title'] ?></div>
       <img src="<?php echo base_url('image/' .$news_item['picture']);?>" style="max-width:210px; max-height:180px;"><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <p><?php echo $news_item['body'] ?></p>
      <p>Category: &nbsp; <?php echo $news_item['category']?><br /><br />
      Posted on:&nbsp;  <?php echo $news_item['date']?>
      </p>
      <a href="news/view/<?php echo $news_item['slug'] ?>" class="btn">View article</a><br /><br />
      <?php endforeach ?>
      <?php echo $links; ?>
```

Comment: `$config["uri_segment"] = 3;` try this

Comment: Same difference. It doesnt change

Answer (score 0):

Change the following and try, your page offset is the last segment of the url, so its 4

```
$config["per_page"] = 1;
$config["uri_segment"] = 4;


$page = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;
```

Comment: It did not change. What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you echo the html form `$data["links"]` and `echo $this->db->last_query()` in model after `$query = $this->db->get("knowbank");` and post it

Comment: please check out my view..i have updated it. Maybe that could be the problem

Comment: Sorry i dont mean your view, i mean the actual html product by the pagination , ie value for  <?php echo $links; ?> in the view or `echo $data["links"];` in controller. And when you click on the next page on your pagination display the actual query using `echo $this->db->last_query()` in your model then  upload the link html and query